# How to make a timer count up ever second then reset to 0 when the character dies

Tags: godot, godot4

So, I made a game where you dodge drones as an Alien and I need help on adding a feature where the timer (Called PlayerTimer,located in the player node) counts up every time you are alive, then when the character dies it resets to 0. Right now, I've tried to look thing up but nothing is happening.

Here's what I have in my Main scene, my text is called *TimerUI* and my Timer is called *PlayerTimer*

[image: .]

Comment: Hi, I'd like to help but I assume you've also got some GDScript (or C# code if using mono version) already for your timer and character die, if you can please share

Answer (score 1):

The timer node only counting down. Assume you're using Godot 4 with GDScript, you could use function `Time.get_ticks_msec()` to get current time counted from when the engine started in miliseconds:

```
onready var timer_ui = $TimerUI
var is_counting = false
var start_time
var elapsed_time_in_sec

func set_timer(is_start):
    if is_start:
        is_counting = true
        start_time = Time.get_ticks_msec()
    else:
        is_counting = false
        elapsed_time_in_sec = 0
        timer_ui.text = elapsed_time_in_sec

func _process(delta):
    if is_counting:
        elapsed_time = floor((Time.get_ticks_msec() - start_time) / 1000)
        timer_ui.text = elapsed_time_in_sec
```

Here you can call `set_timer()` to start the timer when `is_start` is `true` and stop it when it's `false`.